# Make Button Ignore ENTER key pressed c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

im building a page using ASP.NET, however, the first element of my page is a Button and there are other elements below it, however, if the client types something and it shows a confirmation box, and he presses ENTER key, it activates the first button at the page.

I tried to change the tab order does not work.

sorry for noob question xD

Comment: have you tried change accept button of your page in properties?

Comment: that's not the case. for example, if im using a grid, and editing something that does not need to use enter, but I do use. it activates the first button.

Comment: you mean by active is calling method handler or showing the button? can you put your code to clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting **UseSubmitBehavior=False** on the first button?

Comment: THank you that's what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Don't handle the click event. Handle the MouseClick event instead. So whatever code is in click, simply move to the MouseClick event